# Committing a running docker container (with pause), then run it, what's the images internal state

Tags: docker, backup, commit

Let's assume I have a Python program running inside a docker container

```
import time
counter = 0
while True:
   counter += 1
   print counter
   time.sleep(1)
```

What happens if I do a commit on that running container, and then use that new image to run a new container?

The docs state that a running container is paused (cgroups freezer), and after commiting it gets unpaused. In what state is the image in? SIGKILL? I assume that the python program won't be running anymore when doing a docker start on that image, correct?

I'm asking because I have a couple of Java servers (Atlassian) running in the container, so I wonder if I'm doing daily backups via commit on that container, and I then "restore" (docker run ... backup/20160118) one of the backups, in what state will the servers be in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker commit only commits the *filesystem* changes of a container, so any file that has been added, removed, or modified on the filesystem since the container was started.

Note that any *volume* (`--volume` or `VOLUME` inside the dockerfile) is *not* part of the container's filesystem, so won't be committed.

#### In-memory state: "Checkpoint and Restore"

Committing a container, *including* it's current (in-memory) state, is a lot more complex. This process is called "checkpoint and restore". You can find more information about this on https://criu.org. There's currently a pull request to add basic support for checkpoint and restore to Docker; https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/13602, but that feature does not yet support "migrating" such containers to a different machine.